# How is the formula of Shannon Entropy derived?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

From this slide, it's said that *the smallest possible number of bits per symbol* is as the Shannon Entropy formula defined:
[image]

I've read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331103/intuitive-explanation-of-entropy), and still not quite understand how is this formula derived from the perspective of encoding with bits.

I'd like to get some tips like in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730206/how-to-make-the-encoding-of-symbols-needs-only-1-58496-bits-symbol-as-carried-ou), and please don't tell me that it's just because this is the only formula which satisfies the properties of a entropy function.

Thx in advance~

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663351/what-does-the-logpx-mean-in-the-calculation-of-entropy.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, I could agree to this formula qualitatively, but quantitatively, how to prove it's the smallest number of **bits**?

Comment: @zhangxaochen : That is precisely the first theorem of Shannon, it's a fundamental (simple though not trivial) result that is explained in every textbook of Information Theory, see eg. [Cover- Thomas](http://www.amazon.com/Elements-Information-Edition-Telecommunications-Processing/dp/0471241954). This is too broad for getting an answer here IMO

Answer (score 3):

Suggest you read the proof that H is the only measure (up to a constant) that satisfies the axioms of information measure. It can be found here: "The Mathematical Theory of Communication" - Shannon & Weaver.

The proof of the theorem is easy to understand - only a couple of pages.

Answer (score 2):

Log2 1/p is the number of bits needed to transmit symbols that occur with probability p.  For example, if it occurs 1 times in 8, we need 3 bits to encode all 8 possibilities. Now just take the average number of bits weighted by p for each symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple intuitive construction of Shannon's Entropy formula:
[Understanding Shannon's Entropy...](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.2061.pdf)